# Добавление и удаление данных из избранного, php

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Разрабатываю проект, делаю избранное, после авторизации пользователь может добавить в избранное маршрут автобуса. Но столкнулся с проблемой, при добавлении можно добавить 9 записей(хотя в бд их 8) и первую запись можно добавить один раз, а последнюю запись можно добавить все 9 раз. Это первое. Второе, удаление очень странно работает, когда в избранном 1 запись, оно удаляет хорошо, когда от 2 и выше, то удаляет только некоторые, а остальные остаются не удаленными. Это второе. И третье(не обязательно, но было бы полезно). Можно ли как-то сохранять эти данные? Типа пользователь вышел, зашел и данные на месте. Я использовал сессии, но при выходе сессия уничтожается. Спасибо. Код предоставляю.

Добавление маршрутов:

```
$status="";
if (isset($_POST['id_flight']) && $_POST['id_flight']){
    $id_flight = $_POST['id_flight'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT id_flight, nameBus, departurePoint, arrivalPoint FROM flight WHERE `id_flight`='$id_flight'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $nameBus = $row['nameBus'];
    $id_flight = $row['id_flight'];
    $departurePoint = $row['departurePoint'];
    $arrivalPoint = $row['arrivalPoint'];
    $cartArray = array(
        $id_flight=>array(
        'nameBus'=>$nameBus,
        'id_flight'=>$id_flight,
        'departurePoint'=>$departurePoint,
        'arrivalPoint'=>$arrivalPoint)
    );
    if(empty($_SESSION["favv"])) {
        $_SESSION["favv"] = $cartArray;
        $status = "<div class='box'>Маршрут додано до обраного!</div>";
    } else {
        $array_keys = array_keys($_SESSION["favv"]);
        if(in_array($id_flight, $array_keys)) {
            $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>Маршрут уже додано до обраного!</div>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION["favv"] = array_merge($_SESSION["favv"],$cartArray);
            $status = "<div class='box'>Маршрут додано до обраного!</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Удаление маршрута:

```
$status="";
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="remove"){
    if(!empty($_SESSION["favv"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["favv"] as $key => $value) {
            if($_POST["id_flight"] == $key){
                unset($_SESSION["favv"][$key]);
                $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>
                Маршрут видалено з обраного</div>";
            }
            if(empty($_SESSION["favv"]))
                unset($_SESSION["favv"]);
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="change"){
    foreach($_SESSION["favv"] as &$value){
        if($value['id_flight'] === $_POST["id_flight"]){
            break; // Stop the loop after we've found the product
        }
    }
}
```

Гляньте, что может быть не так и дайте совет студенту либо же помогите с решением сего чуда

Comment: Храните пользователей и избранное в базе. Тогда ничего пропадать не будет

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо за ответ. Я уже над этим думал, но у меня на носу сдача диплома и переделывать нету особого времени. Это вообще не так горит, как первые два вопроса. Код, честно скажу, скомуниздил с зарубежного ресурса, там была корзина, но я решил под себя сделать. Сделал, но работает не так как хотелось.